# Why the Android Studio need to download Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

[image: building Gradle project info]

I already use Gradle 2.1, why it is downloading the 12.2?
I had downloaded 2.1-all.zip. Where does Android Studio store the temporary file?

Answer (score 2):

> I already use Gradle 2.1, why it is downloading the 12.2?

It is downloading 1.12, not 12.2. It is doing so because the Gradle for Android plugin does not support Gradle 2.x at this time -- the newest Gradle it supports is 1.12.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle uses [the wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) to import your project. Wrapper downloads Gradle version specified in the `gradle/wrapper/gardle-wrapper.properties file and downloads it to its own cache (inside`~/.gradle/caches` directory).
When using the wrapper, any existing Gradle distribution installed on the machine is ignored.